# Rexster extension using Neo4j Lucene index

Tags: neo4j, lucene, tinkerpop, rexster

I'm trying to write a `Rexster` extension in `Java` that among other things queries nodes using `Neo4j 2.0 Lucene indices`.

From the few threads I was able to find (mostly old Google Group threads), it doesn't seem to be possible using `Blueprint's Graph`.

I thought about a possible solution where I access the underlying `Neo4jGraph` class from the extension's:

```
@RexsterContext Graph graph
```

parameter, but I'm not sure how to do this.

The end-goal ideally, would be to use an automatic `get-or-create-index` method which could be called with a piece of text on a `Lucene index`.

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you said the answer here:

> I thought about a possible solution where I access the underlying
>   Neo4jGraph class from the extension's:
>
> @RexsterContext Graph graph

If you need methods from Blueprints `Neo4jGraph` then just cast `Graph` to that:

```
Neo4jGraph neo4j = (Neo4jGraph) neo4j;
```

Furthermore, if you need to work with specific, native Neo4j classes/methods then just do:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphdb = neo4j.getRawGraph()
```

Obviously both of these approaches makes your Rexster Extension Neo4j specific but it sounds like that is ok for your case.